# Javascript Async/await with axios resolve pending

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await

I have a simple, question. I try to found a solution on web but every try failed.
I have this code:

```
   const getSideBarMenu1 = async () => {
      let myArray = []
      await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(res => {
        console.log('res1', res)
        myArray = res.data
      }).catch(err => console.log(err))
      console.log('myArray', myArray)
      return myArray
    }
```

And when I use this function like this:

```
 const useFunction = getSideBarMenu1()
    console.log('useFunction', useFunction)
```

the result of console log is:

```
useFunction Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Array(100)
```

How to save the PromoseResult inside a variable?
Thank you everyone!

Comment: It's because `getSideBarMenu1` is an Async function. So you need to call it with `await getSideBarMenu1()`

Comment: Unexpected reserved word 'await' is what terminal return. I'm using vuexy template for VueJS

Comment: You can use `.then()`. A promise can be called by the await only within an async function. So you can do the following `getSideBarMenu1().then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the promise to fulfill, before accessing its result:

```
const useFunction = await getSideBarMenu1()
```

Comment: terminal give me syntax error : Unexpected reserved word 'await'. –

Answer (score 1):

`getSideBarMenu1` is `async` that returns a `Promise`, meaning you have to await it.

```js
const useFunction = await getSideBarMenu1();
```

You can also use `.then()`

Comment: I know! But if I use await i can't compile.
terminal give me syntax error : Unexpected reserved word 'await'.

Answer (score 0):

You can also return data directly from `getSideBarMenu1` function:

```js
const getSideBarMenu1 = async () => {
  const {data} = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  return data
}


const useFunction = await getSideBarMenu1()
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a little keyword here.

```js
const useFunction = await getSideBarMenu1()
console.log('useFunction', useFunction)
```

article source: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/04/30/vue-fetch-http-get-request-examples
video source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHfyF0B4y8E